# Date Range Overlap with Nullable Dates

Tags: language-agnostic, datetime, math

I'm looking for an extended answer to the question asked here:

[Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

where any of the dates in either date range can be null. I've come up with the following solution, but I'm not sure if it can be simplified further.

```
(StartA == NULL || StartA <= EndB) &&
(EndA == NULL || EndA >= StartB) &&
(StartB == NULL || StartB <= EndA) &&
(EndB == NULL || EndB >= StartA)
```

Assuming:

DateTime ranges of StartA to EndA and StartB to EndB

**EDIT:**  Sorry I quickly threw the above logic together, which seems to fail when either range's start and end dates are NULL.  See David's solution below for a better & well-explained approach.

Comment: you'll have an error if StartA is null, because the compare operator doesn't works with null. Convert all the or Gate{Logic} to and{Logic} then reorganize the statements by putting all compare to null at the start so the short circuit and{Logic} will work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This case can be handled by a slight generalization of [Charles Bretana's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap/325964#325964) to that question.

> Let CondA Mean DateRange A Completely After DateRange B (True if StartA > EndB)
> Let CondB Mean DateRange A Completely Before DateRange B (True if EndA < StartB)

In this case, assuming you want a null date to represent "no starting/ending bound," the conditions are modified. For `CondA`, for instance, in order for DateRange A to be completely after DateRange B, DateRange A must have a defined starting time, DateRange B must have a defined ending time, *and* the starting time of A must be after the ending time of B:

```
CondA := (StartA != null) && (EndB != null) && (StartA > EndB)
```

`CondB` is the same with A and B switched:

```
CondB := (StartB != null) && (EndA != null) && (StartB > EndA)
```

Continuing,

> Then Overlap exists if Neither A Nor B is true

```
Overlap := !(CondA || CondB)
```

and

> Now deMorgan's law, I think it is, says that
>
> Not (A Or B) <=> Not A And Not B

```
Overlap == !CondA && !CondB
        == ![(StartA != null) && (EndB != null) && (StartA > EndB)] &&
           ![(StartB != null) && (EndA != null) && (StartB > EndA)]
        == [(StartA == null) || (EndB == null) || (StartA <= EndB)] &&
           [(StartB == null) || (EndA == null) || (StartB <= EndA)]
```

I think this is actually a bit more robust than the solution you developed, because if `EndB == NULL` but `StartA` is not null, your first condition will wind up comparing `StartA <= NULL`. In most languages I'm familiar with, that's an error condition.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, David!  Yeah, I realized my initial solution falls apart pretty quickly soon after I posted it.

Comment: Nice Approach as deMorgan's law, But you can not implement the second part as programming statement, because if any of startA or EndB as example are equal to null, the the compare operator will fail.
Try to keep just the And {&&} operator, because it will work as a short circuit in most new compilers.
This is Correct as low and as programming.
![(StartA != null) && (EndB != null) && (StartA > EndB)] &&
           ![(StartB != null) && (EndA != null) && (StartB > EndA)]

Comment: @Waleed: If you're talking about my final two lines of code, that certainly can be implemented as a statement. If `startA` or `endB` is equal to `null`, that will get caught by the explicit tests for that condition and the `<=` comparison will never be made. `||` also uses short-circuit evaluation. (Most compilers would probably optimize using DeMorgan's law so that the last two lines and the preceding two lines would generate the same compiled code.)

Answer (score 1):

Without considering nulls, answer is

`(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)`
  (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap/325964#325964) for detailed explanation)

considering nulls for start and end dates,
Using C Ternary operator syntax:
   `(StartA != null? StartA: EndB <= EndB != null? EndB: StartA) && 
     (EndA != null? EndA: StartB >= StartB != null? StartB: EndA)`

Or C# 4.x style null operators:

`(StartA??EndB <= EndB??StartA) && (EndA??StartB >= StartB??EndA)`

or in SQL:

`(Coalesce(StartA, EndB) <= Coalesce(EndB, StartA)) 
   And (Coalesce(EndA, StartB ) <= Coalesce(StartB , EndA))`

Explanation:
consider the non-null answer:
`(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)`

Now, consider that StartA is null, indicating that date range A has existed since beginning of time (BOT). In that case, DateRangeB can never be before DateRangeA. So first condition, (StartA(BOT) <= EndB) will ALWAYS be true, no matter what EndB is. So change this expression so that instead of comparing null with EndB, when StartA is null, compare EndB with itself 
No matter what EndB is, the expression `EndB <= EndB` will be true.
(We could create variables to represent BOT and EOT, but this is easier).

Do the same for other three input variables.

Answer (score -1):

That is probably as 'simple' as you can get it, although I haven't actually proven it.

It probably isn't worth it to simplify further, since that block ends up being about 8 operations in the worst case (4 on average thanks to short-circuit evaluation).

Answer (score -1):

All answers are based if the condition is true. I'would like to add some note here.

1- The [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.aspx) variable type is a struct and you can not set it to null unless that you are using nullable type like "DateTime?"

2- To find the overlap range follow the following steps

```
DateTime? StartOverLap = null,EndOverLap = null;
            if (StartA != null && StartB != null)
            {
                StartOverLap = StartA > StartB ? StartA : StartB;
            }
            else if (StartA == null && StartB != null)
            {
                StartOverLap = StartB;
            }
            else if (StartA != null && StartB == null)
            {
                StartOverLap = StartA;
            }
            if (EndA != null && EndB != null)
            {
                EndOverLap = EndA < EndB ? EndA : EndB;
            }
            else if (EndA == null && EndB != null)
            {
                EndOverLap = EndB;
            }
            else if (EndA != null && EndB == null)
            {
                EndOverLap = EndA;
            }
            if (StartOverLap != null && EndOverLap == null)
            {
                if (EndOverLap < StartOverLap)
                {
                    StartOverLap = null;
                    EndOverLap = null;
                }
            }
```